# New features to shapefile in QGIS end up with previous features attribute values - why?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes

When I digitize a new feature to a polygon shapefile in QGIS the attribute data of the new polygon is replaced by the data entered into the last feature created.  Has anyone else ran into this issue?  Is there a way to fix it?

For example, I may generate a polygon and give it the NAME value of "Gizmo", and dateMade value of "2016-06-12" but when I hit "okay" to confirm it, the complete feature will have a NAME and dateMade value of the previously made feature.  To correct this I have to generate the feature, save it, and then go and edit the feature adding the correct information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the menubar, go to:

```
Settings > Options > Digitizing > Feature creation
```

and disable the `Reuse last entered attribute values` setting:

[image: Digitizing settings]

(*I'm sure this was asked before but can't find the post.*)

Comment: This is useful information for me - I had upgraded QGIS from version 2.12 to the newer 2.14, and created a new copy of the shapefile in question and that had been working but this setting sounds like what was causing my issues and changing it on and off is much quicker than rebuilding a workspace.

Comment: @JonJon - Glad it was helpful :)